# generating all possible k partition of an array

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recursive-algorithms, data-structure

actually, I confronted a problem for generating all possible k partitions of an array. I tried to write the algorithm but actually, I am not able to.

can anybody please give me the idea, how to code this problem ?

### for example

suppose I am given an array A[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
and k = 3, then I have to write the code for all possible partition for k =3.
  in this example, our all possible partitions are for k =3 is as follows 
  {1}, {2}, {3, 4, 5}
  {1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}
  {1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}
  {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}
  {1, 2, 3} , {4}, {5}
  {1}, {2, 3, 4}, {5}

thanks,
any effort is appreciatable.

Answer (score 1):

If we look closely at the problem, the only thing to determine here is the $k-1$ places in the array where to put "breaks" to separate it into $k$ sets. You can generate all those combinations with nested loops or recursion. For reference, see [Stars and Bars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Is it maybe that one such partition you are looking for would also be, say
$$\{2\},\{3,4\},\{5,1\}?$$

If yes, then you will also need to generate all permutations of an array before doing the stars and bars. You can generate all permutations with [Heap's algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm).